# Autodelete over multiple sheets in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script written to auto delete rows in my sheet when the date in column K are less than the current date.  I have recently added some new tabs within my sheet and cannot get the code to delete those new tabs.  The date remains in column K on the new tabs.  Here is the script.  What adjustments do I need to make to make this work?

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Clear Carry Overs",
    functionName : "Update"
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};

function Update(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I CHANGED THE CODE TO NOW READ:
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().
  getSheets();
   for(i in sheets)  {
      var sheet = sheets[i];}
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = rows.getNumColumns();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var date = new Date();

  for (var i = 5; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var row = values[i];
    //Logger.log(row[1])
    if(row[1] != ''){
      var sheetDate = new Date(row[10]);
      Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date, 'CST', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
      SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, 'CST', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
      if (Sdate.valueOf() > SsheetDate.valueOf()){
        for(j=2; j < numColumns; j++){
          var valuee = sheet.getRange(i+1, j).clearContent();
        }
        Logger.log("Row " + (i+1) + " was deleted")
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

new code:

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

with:

```
var sheets= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
 for(i in sheets) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
```

then add a closing curly brace `}` at the bottom.

```
function Update(){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
   for(i in sheets) {
     var sheet = sheets[i];
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = rows.getNumColumns();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var date = new Date();

  for (var i = 5; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var row = values[i];
    //Logger.log(row[1])
    if(row[1] != ''){
      var sheetDate = new Date(row[10]);
      Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date, 'CST', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
      SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, 'CST', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
      if (Sdate.valueOf() > SsheetDate.valueOf()){
        for(j=2; j < numColumns; j++){
          var valuee = sheet.getRange(i+1, j).clearContent();
        }
        Logger.log("Row " + (i+1) + " was deleted")
      } 
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the other sheets don't auto delet unless I manually run the script while on each tab.

Comment: did you remove the line. 'var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); ' and replace it with the code shown? if so, the only way I will be able to tell what's going on is to see your Revised Code.

Comment: it wont let me copy and past the new code here.  is there another way we can communicate?

Comment: you can try editing your original post and adding the new code below the existing.another way might be by posting it to Google+ and then adding a link in the comments.